# Php: HTML bullet list to multidimensional array

Tags: php

I used to do a bit of php programming years ago but I'm way out of practice so I wondered if I could get a bit of help?

I want to convert a html bulleted list into a multidimensional array. The bullet list contains 4 levels of indentation and will be sent to the function in text/string format (not a file). The html will only contain ol and li tags (e.g. no doctype, head, title etc.)

I figure this should be an easy thing to do but when I search I can only find array to html list rather than html list to array.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers, Dan.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.